# Error 1004 when multiplying cell values based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which looks at a range of cells. Every other cell is either a 1 or a 0 (sign bit). Depending on the sign bit, the next cell (a normal number) is multiplied either by 1 or 0. I keep getting a run time error `1004 Application-defined or object-defined error` on the body of the `ElseIf` of the `If` statement (indicated below). Not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code is in a "proof-of-concept" stage so it's still pretty hackish.

```
Dim N As Long
------------------------------------------
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
x = 0
y = 1

N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)
If N > Columns.Count Then
    N = Columns.Count
Else
    For i = 4 To 9999
        Cells(1, i).ClearContents
        Cells(3, i).ClearContents
    Next i
End If

For i = 4 To N + 3
    x = x + y
    Cells(1, i) = x
Next i

For i = 4 To N + 3
    If Cells(2, i) = 1 Then
        Cells(2, i).Offset(0, 1).Select = Cells(2, i).Offset(0, 1).Select * -1
    ElseIf Cells(2, i) = 0 Then

'This is the line with errors vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

        Cells(2, i).Offset(0, 1).Select = Cells(2, i).Offset(0, 1).Select * 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using `Select`. Obviously, `Select` and `Activate` don't give you values. They select or activate the cell, not different from manually clicking on them using the mouse or moving/activating to them using the keyboard or what else. Multiplying them by a value is a major no-no.

The `Range` property you should be looking for is `Value`. In any case, I think you're making it difficult because of having two loops. You really should reconsider your design pattern. In any case, here's my approach (mine's vertical, but it seems like yours is horizontal, so be clear exactly what is on your end so this can be adjusted).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Iter As Long
    Dim CurrCell As Range
    Const Col = 1

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS = .Sheets("Sheet3") 'Change as necessary.
    End With

    With WS
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Iter = 1 To LastRow 'Change as necessary.
            Set CurrCell = .Cells(Iter, Col)
            Select Case CurrCell.Value
                Case 1
                    CurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = (CurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value * (-1))
                Case 0
                    CurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = (CurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value * 1) 'Is this even necessary? It's an identity.
            End Select
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.